# running QT Jambi applicantion on Win64

Tags: qt, runtime, win64, qt-jambi, jambi

I've been evaluating QT Jambi for an application I'm developing, and on the way I've read that QT Jambi faces some troubles at development time on Win64. However, I won't develop on Win64 so it doesn't matter for now, but what I really need to know is whether an application that is built using QT Jambi would run seamlessly on Win64 or not.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is basic support for win64 already present, there just haven’t been releases for that platform. So I assure you, win64 will work as win32 does, there shouldn’t be any differences.

Comment: Have you actually tried?  I can tell you I have been trying all day long, below is my error.  I was hoping not to have build the C++ source as that is something I barely have any experience with:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Loading library failed, progress so far:
Unpacking .jar file: 'qtjambi-win32-msvc2005-4.6.3.jar'
Checking Archive 'qtjambi-win32-msvc2005-4.6.3.jar'
 - skipping because of wrong system: trying to load: 'win32', expected: 'win64'

Comment: You are trying to load win32 packages instead of win64 packages. It does work, you can ask more info from our mailing list or irc channel... Or even throw the log here and hope we’ll spot it :)